# create a form and given with Laravel sauvgarde of 5

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I am a beginner and am using laravel 5, i have same problem with recovring data and saving them.
i think that some thing is  missing .
this a source code:

this the blade page: .blade.php

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('AjoutAnnonce') }}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name of the building</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" value="{{ old('nom') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>



                                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="emplacement" id="test2" value="{{ '$myLatlng' }}">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Description</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="description"  value="{{ old('description') }}"> </textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

this the controlleur:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use App\Immobilier;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Validator;

class AnnonceController extends  Controller
{
    public $restful = true;

    public function get_index()
    {
        return view('AjoutAnnonce');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data){
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'nom' => 'required|max:255',
            'description' => 'required | max:600' ,
            
        ]);
    }
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return immobilier::create([
            'nom' => $data['nom'],
            'description' => $data['description'],
            'id_promoteur' => Auth::user()->id
        ]);
    }
    public function post_index()
    {

        return view('AjoutAnnonce');
    }
}
```

and this the request:

```html
<?php


namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class AnnonceRequest extends Request {
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules()
    {

        return [
            'nom' => 'required',
            'description'=> 'required|max;600'
        ];


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rule should be:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'nom' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required|max:600' //not max;600
    ];
}
```

This is probably making it fail validation every time.